# Why selecting last line without pager doesnt work?

Tags: jquery

http://jsbin.com/utusiz/6/edit

I want to select the **last** line in the grid **without** the pager  !

meaning for me :

select the **last TR** where this TR does **not** has **table** in it.

what am i missing?

[image]

```
$('.mySortAble').find('tbody tr:last:not(:has(table)) td').css('background-color','red')
```

### p.s. edit

please ignore the Grid_Item class. its not always there. (sorry)

Comment: The relevant code cannot be included in the question?

Comment: @JaredFarrish did you open the jsbin ? its there.

Comment: No I didn't. Hence my comment. (And yes I'm annoyed generally by *Click here and dig through my code to find my problem*. `;)`)

Comment: @JaredFarrish my friend its just 1 line of code :)

Comment: Then post it IN THE QUESTION. You are making my point for me. `:)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish :) ok got it :)

Comment: I see `class="Grid_Item"` on all but the pager. Couldn't you find the last of that class, `tr.Grid_Item:last`?

Comment: Are you *actually* trying to select all but the last row?

Comment: @amnotiam yes. ( the last row for me is the one which has table in it)

Comment: @Jared Farrish see my edit please. and the new link which i removed the class from. sorry

Comment: You should be using my answer you accepted earlier. But just use `.slice()` like `$('.mySortAble > tbody > tr').slice(0,-1)`. You can't use `.find()`, because it will also search the nested table. And then you were selecting the `:last` row (which is inside the nested table).

Comment: @amnotiam But how can i be sure that i slice the last row which is a pager ? not all grids have pager. I stick to my question : How can i select the last tr which not has table in it ?

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll add an answer.

Comment: @amnotiam Im going crazy why my selector doesnt work ...:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6743/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-am-not-i-am)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'll just post my answer from your previous question since it still works *(but updated to use the `mySortAble` class)*.

```
 $('.mySortAble > tbody > tr')
           .slice(1)
           .filter('tr:not(:has(table))')
           .css('background-color','red');
```

or you could do it like this...

```
 $('.mySortAble > tbody > tr')
           .slice(1)
           .not('tr:has(table)')
           .css('background-color','red');
```

---

Or if you already have a reference to the table...

```
var tmp = $('.mySortAble');

tmp.children()
   .children()
   .slice(1)
   .filter('tr:not(:has(table))')
   .css('background-color','red');
```

Comment: lets say .mySortAble is stored on $(tmp) - whats your code will be now ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: In your code, the `.find()` was getting *all* nested rows, including the ones in the nested table. So `:last` was giving you the last row found, which happened to be in the nested table. And `:not(:has(table))` did not apply because that row does not have a nested table.

Comment: ...`'.mySortAble > tbody > tr'` this targets only the rows of the outer table. Then either the `.filter()` or the `.not()` will modify that set of rows to exclude the one that has a nested table.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That solution was in my other answer as well. I'll add it to this one too. Nothing has changed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6742/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-am-not-i-am)

Comment: does the TR from `.find('tbody:first > tr') ` is the same tr from `.filter('tr:not(:has(table))')` ?

Comment: Demo of the immediately above comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xznRp/ (More specific to the answer example: http://jsfiddle.net/xznRp/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making it too complicated.  Your grid rows have a class `Grid_Item` on it, your pager dom elements do not.  Why don't you select the last `tr` with that class?

Comment: @please ignore that class its not always there :) see my edit.

Comment: why don't you add it then, even if it has nothing to do with styling?  or add an attribute like `grid-row=true` and search for that?

Comment: i dont want to add it. ( I cant  - this is the code) i removed the class in the new link. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

maybe use

```
$('tr.Grid_Item:last').css('background-color','red');
```